# Postgresql error syntax error at or near "END;"

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Can someone explain why it throws error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END;"` at this block of code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_equal(object objects []) RETURNS text [] AS $$
DECLARE uuids text [];
BEGIN 

IF object.object_type = 'flat' THEN
SELECT array_agg(uuid)
FROM objects
WHERE open = true
    AND object_type = object.object_type
    AND square_meters = object.square_meters
    AND floor = object.floor
    AND total_floors = object.total_floors
    AND latitude = object.latitude
    AND longitude = object.longitude INTO uuids;

    
ELSE IF object.object_type = 'house' THEN
SELECT array_agg(uuid)
FROM objects
WHERE open = true
    AND object_type = object.object_type
    AND square_meters = object.square_meters
    AND floor = object.floor
    AND total_floors = object.total_floors
    AND latitude = object.latitude
    AND longitude = object.longitude INTO uuids;
    
ELSE IF object.object_type = 'commercial_space' THEN
SELECT array_agg(uuid)
FROM objects
WHERE open = true
    AND object_type = object.object_type
    AND square_meters = object.square_meters
    AND latitude = object.latitude
    AND longitude = object.longitude INTO uuids;
    
ELSE
SELECT array_agg(uuid)
FROM objects
WHERE open = true
    AND object_type = object.object_type
    AND lot_size = object.lot_size
    AND latitude = object.latitude
    AND longitude = object.longitude INTO uuids;
END IF;

RETURN uuids;

END; <--- throws error here
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But not here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_equal(object objects []) RETURNS text [] AS $$
DECLARE uuids text [];
BEGIN 

IF object.object_type = 'flat' THEN
SELECT array_agg(uuid)
FROM objects
WHERE open = true
    AND object_type = object.object_type
    AND square_meters = object.square_meters
    AND floor = object.floor
    AND total_floors = object.total_floors
    AND latitude = object.latitude
    AND longitude = object.longitude INTO uuids;
    
ELSE
SELECT array_agg(uuid)
FROM objects
WHERE open = true
    AND object_type = object.object_type
    AND lot_size = object.lot_size
    AND latitude = object.latitude
    AND longitude = object.longitude INTO uuids;
END IF;

RETURN uuids;

END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Try replacing ELSE IF by ELSEIF. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-if-else-statements/

Comment: What McNets said ^^. You have 3 IFs and only 1 END IF. Replacing all `ELSE IF` with `ELSIF`,  should remove the issue.

Comment: Ohh, ok thanks. It works now. Could not find the solution for past two hours and after all it was this simple.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this was to change **ELSE IF** to **ELSEIF** without the space in between, because that's the correct syntax for postgresql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_equal(object objects []) RETURNS text [] AS $$
DECLARE uuids text [];
BEGIN 

IF object.object_type = 'flat' THEN
SELECT array_agg(uuid)
FROM objects
WHERE open = true
    AND object_type = object.object_type
    AND square_meters = object.square_meters
    AND floor = object.floor
    AND total_floors = object.total_floors
    AND latitude = object.latitude
    AND longitude = object.longitude INTO uuids;

    
ELSEIF object.object_type = 'house' THEN
SELECT array_agg(uuid)
FROM objects
WHERE open = true
    AND object_type = object.object_type
    AND square_meters = object.square_meters
    AND floor = object.floor
    AND total_floors = object.total_floors
    AND latitude = object.latitude
    AND longitude = object.longitude INTO uuids;
    
ELSEIF object.object_type = 'commercial_space' THEN
SELECT array_agg(uuid)
FROM objects
WHERE open = true
    AND object_type = object.object_type
    AND square_meters = object.square_meters
    AND latitude = object.latitude
    AND longitude = object.longitude INTO uuids;
    
ELSE
SELECT array_agg(uuid)
FROM objects
WHERE open = true
    AND object_type = object.object_type
    AND lot_size = object.lot_size
    AND latitude = object.latitude
    AND longitude = object.longitude INTO uuids;
END IF;

RETURN uuids;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Yeah. The word is `ELSIF` but as the [docs about Control Structures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html) state: *"The key word `ELSIF` can also be spelled `ELSEIF`."*